# How do I make a WebBrowser render WebPages correctly?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.Win32;

[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]

public class Program : Form

{       

private WebBrowser webBrowser;

public Program()
{
    InitialiseForm();
}

public void InitialiseForm()
{
    webBrowser = new WebBrowser();
    Controls.AddRange(new Control[] {webBrowser});
    webBrowser.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
    webBrowser.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;

    webBrowser.Navigate("http://www.nationalgeographic.com/");

}

[STAThread]

public static void Main()
{
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.Run(new Program());
}
```

I was told to paste this mountain of code below in my set up and I have done just that. I dont even know what it does. I just want to build a webBrowser using a C# WebView. Why is this becoming so Complicated and how do I make the WebBrowser render pages properly. It is showing only a blank page with a horizontal line on my webView and also on the internet explorer version running on my computer. The webpage I am trying to display is nationalgeographic.com.Please help

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var appName = Process.GetCurrentProcess().ProcessName + ".exe";
        SetIE8KeyforWebBrowserControl(appName);
}  

private void SetIE8KeyforWebBrowserControl(string appName) {
        RegistryKey Regkey = null;
        try
        {
                // For 64 bit machine
            //if (Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem)
                //Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\MAIN\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);

//else  
//For 32 bit machine
        Regkey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Internet Explorer\\Main\\FeatureControl\\FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION", true);


    // If the path is not correct or
    // if the user haven't priviledges to access the registry
    if (Regkey == null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed - Address Not found");
        return;
    }

    string FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

    // Check if key is already present
    if (FindAppkey == "8000")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Required Application Settings Present");
        Regkey.Close();
        return;
    }

    // If a key is not present add the key, Key value 8000 (decimal)
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FindAppkey))
        Regkey.SetValue(appName, unchecked((int)0x1F40), RegistryValueKind.DWord);

    // Check for the key after adding
    FindAppkey = Convert.ToString(Regkey.GetValue(appName));

    if (FindAppkey == "8000")
        MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Applied Successfully");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed, Ref: " + FindAppkey);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Application Settings Failed");
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    // Close the Registry
    if (Regkey != null)
        Regkey.Close();
}
```

}

}

Comment: Does no one here know how to make a fully functioning webBrowser in c sharp?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The web browser used in .NET is internet explorer, and you can determine the version from : `WebBrowser.Version`, I suggest using Chromium web browser it is available as nuget package and can be used as windows form or WPF control, and supports html 5 and it is better than IE, check their project and search for tutorials for C#, check this link : https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying about down votes, if you think that I am the one who put a down vote for you then you are mistaken :)

Comment: I think there are some sort of downvote bots or some Internet Trolls on this site.

Comment: @John All you've done is dump two poorly formatted pieces of code, and not really asked any question. StackOverflow isn't a personal coding service, and when people read stuff like "I was told to paste this mountain of code below in my set up and I have done just that. I dont even know what it does" it just shows you don't actually have any interest in solving your problem, but rather someone just come along and do it for you. See: http://slash7.com/2006/12/22/vampires/